# Chat inbox icon with number of unread messages should be a pixel wider

Tags: bug, design, chat, top-bar, global-inbox

It seems that [chat page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site) inbox item is not wide enough to overlap empty inbox icon. So the odd gray pixels break through the top:

> [image: screenshot of the top navigation bar with an inbox indicator showing 1 unread message]

Zoomed in:

> [image: zoomed in screenshot of the top navigation bar with the 1-pixel shift highlighted]

And animated version when number goes away:

> [image: animation showing the 1 unread message indicator disappearing on click]

Comment: @Joachim there is no mobile version anymore, it was replaced by responsive design.

Comment: @Joachim [mobile version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elIkr.jpg) of that [page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site) doesn't contain inbox at all.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard there's still mobile version of chat pages.

Comment: Sadly so. Well based on screenshot, it's the full site mode.